# How can I get iOS reminders to appear on google calendar?

Tags: ios, calendar, google-calendar, siri, reminders

I like setting reminders using Siri (e.g. "remind me to buy milk tomorrow at 8pm").

Siri understands what I am trying to say and pretty smoothly adds the reminder. I would like this reminder to appear on my google calendar (i.e. some event starting at 8pm ending 15 minutes or 30 minutes later, with my message on the reminder).

How can I do this? I set a ton of reminders using Siri, and this would be a great way for me to get a birds eye view (and maybe a leg up) on all the stuff I have to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: theoretically a dupe, but actually the answer is more than the dupe…. Stop saying "remind me" & say "insert calendar event"

Comment: Will the 'pick a calendar' option in the dupe pick a google calendar? I dumped my Google CalDAV when iCloud took off & so don't have the choice any more